# update trigger after insert on same table

Tags: mysql, trigger, update, insert

So, I'm supposed to make a trigger that applies md5 to a row after an INSERT was made on it.
Here is what I came up with:

```sql
delimiter $$\
create trigger pd_encrip before insert on usuario\
for each row\
begin\
set new.senha=md5(senha);\
end $$\
delimiter ;
```

The trigger compiles, but when I try to insert values to the table I get error code 1054: Unknown column 'senha' in 'NEW', but I am 100% sure that there IS a column with this name on the table. I have tryied several variations to it and read a bunch of troubleshootings but I can't be able to make it work.

Here is the tree of the table:

```
id INT AI PK\
login varchar(100)\
senha varchar(100)\
ultimo_login DATETIME
```

I read that triggers aren't supposed to alter the same table that triggered it, but apparently, there is a way of making it work. Unfortunately, the schemas which I read were a bit too much for me to get it, as a newbie. I just didn't understand.

Can someone help?

Comment: You use `MD5(senha)` whereas you must use `MD5(NEW.senha)`. Also - you use only one statement, so simply `CREATE TRIGGER pd_encrip BEFORE INSERT ON usuario FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.senha=MD5(NEW.senha);`. No BEGIN-END, no DELIMITER.

Comment: *I get error code 1054: Unknown column 'senha' in 'NEW'* ?? You must receive `Unknown column 'senha' in 'field list'`.

Comment: Oh god!
It worked. Damn. Thank u!